# Expected Primary Expression

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;
contract Registration {
struct MultiSig
{
    address institute;
    address student;
Documents documents;   
}
mapping(address=>MultiSig) public wallets ;
function createNewMultiSigbyUser(address instituteaddress) public {
        var wa = wallets[msg.sender];
        wa.institute = instituteaddress;
        wa.studend = msg.sender;
}
}
```

on the var datatype, it says Expected Primary Expression
Please help in correcting this code.

Answer (score 1):

the `var` keyboard is being deprecated in 0.4.20 ([see](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.20)).

You must specify a type, in that case `MultiSig`.

Comment: please can you help me with the fresh code of the above given, i am not able to find out, please help me sir, thankyou

Comment: `function createNewMultiSigbyUser(address instituteaddress) public {
        MultiSig storage wa = wallets[msg.sender];
        wa.institute = instituteaddress;
        wa.studend = msg.sender;
}`

Comment: thankyou sir but still didnt worked for me